# How do I navigate to a parent route from a child route?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

My problem is quite classic. I have a private part of an application which is behind a `login form`. When the login is successful, it goes to a child route for the admin application.

My problem is that I can't use the `global navigation menu` because the router tries to route in my `AdminComponent` instead of my `AppCompoment`. So my navigation is broken.

Another problem is that if someone want to access the URL directly, I want to redirect to the parent "login" route. But I can't make it work. It seems to me like theses two issues are similar.

Any idea how it can be done?

Comment: please add some code

Comment: As pointed out by others, please add some code or the basic routes config so that your question can attract more precise answers.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Do you want a link/HTML or do you want to route imperatively/in code?

**Link**: The RouterLink directive always treats the provided link as a delta to the current URL:

```ts
[routerLink]="['/absolute']"
[routerLink]="['../../parent']"
[routerLink]="['../sibling']"
[routerLink]="['./child']"     // or
[routerLink]="['child']" 

// with route param     ../../parent;abc=xyz
[routerLink]="['../../parent', {abc: 'xyz'}]"
// with query param and fragment   ../../parent?p1=value1&p2=v2#frag
[routerLink]="['../../parent']" [queryParams]="{p1: 'value', p2: 'v2'}" fragment="frag"
```

With RouterLink, remember to import and use the `directives` array:

```ts
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
```

**Imperative**: The `navigate()` method requires a starting point (i.e., the `relativeTo` parameter). If none is provided, the navigation is absolute:

```ts
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
...
this.router.navigate(["/absolute/path"]);
this.router.navigate(["../../parent"], {relativeTo: this.route});
this.router.navigate(["../sibling"],   {relativeTo: this.route});
this.router.navigate(["./child"],      {relativeTo: this.route}); // or
this.router.navigate(["child"],        {relativeTo: this.route});

// with route param     ../../parent;abc=xyz
this.router.navigate(["../../parent", {abc: 'xyz'}], {relativeTo: this.route});
// with query param and fragment   ../../parent?p1=value1&p2=v2#frag
this.router.navigate(["../../parent"], {relativeTo: this.route, 
    queryParams: {p1: 'value', p2: 'v2'}, fragment: 'frag'});

// navigate without updating the URL 
this.router.navigate(["../../parent"], {relativeTo: this.route, skipLocationChange: true});
```

Comment: the `router.navigate(string)` method doesn't seem to exist in the current version of Angular (2.2). I searched in the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html) and only found `navigate(commands: any[], extras?: NavigationExtras) : Promise<boolean>`. Or am I totally missing something?

Comment: @Tomato, you need to put [] around the routes. For example, 

this.router.navigate(["../../parent"], {relativeTo: this.route});

Comment: how do you pass the `relativeTo` data when you are using [routerLink] in the html instead of typescript?

Comment: the same with services?

Comment: For some reason, in my case I have to use `../../../` instead of `../` to navigate to parent (`'/users'` from `'/users/1'`).

Comment: something good to know is, that router and activatedRoute need to be injected in the component itself, this can not be wrapped into a extra service and a method like `goUp`.

Answer (score 74):

This seems to work for me as of Spring 2017:

```
goBack(): void {
  this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

Where your component ctor accepts `ActivatedRoute` and `Router`, imported as follows:

`import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';`

Comment: Rather than a date it would be more useful to mention the Angular version you happen to be using.

Comment: @isherwood I agree. Apologies.  If I remember correctly, I wrote it for Angular 4.0.x and it was still functional in 4.3.x.  Unfortunately I have moved away from Angular now,

Comment: @ne1410s Thanks alot was missing the relative :this.route

Comment: Note: Will NOT work with additional router segments on lazy loaded modules.
EX: `parentPath`: 'work:queue' (which has children) and said children load child module with parameters. `fullCurrentPath`: 'work/shipping/module/list'. The above code can't load `parentPath` from `fullCurrentPath`.

Answer (score 51):

You can navigate to your parent root like this

```
this.router.navigate(['.'], { relativeTo: this.activeRoute.parent });
```

You will need to inject the current active Route in the constructor

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

  }
```

Comment: Adding some explanation would make this answer more useful.

Comment: Many people suggest navigate to sibling by 

this.router.navigate(["../sibling"],   {relativeTo: this.route});

However, this is not working anymore.  I found this answer work probably.  Instead of using '../' to navigate to parent. change relativeTo from this.route to this.route.parent is the correct way

Comment: @TerryLam: Works great for me. ng7 are you certain you are calling this from inside a component or a service provided in your component

Comment: @ChrisLamothe: Oh yes I made a mistake.  It works in general case.  However, it doesn't work in auxiliary routes.  That means this.router.navigate(['../sibling']) is working but not this.router.navigate([{outlets: {'secondary': ['../sibling']}}]).  In auxiliary routing, I have to use this.router.navigate([{outlets: {'secondary': ['sibling']}}], {relativeTo:this.activatedRoute.parent}).

Comment: Also, the navigation method from this answer `this.router.navigate(['.'], {relativeTo: this.activeRoute.parent});` will work correctly in a case, when you use the same component in two paths: /users/create and /users/edit/123. In both cases it'll navigate to parent /users.

The regular navigation with `this.router.navigate([".."], {relativeTo: this.activeRoute})` will work only for the users/create but it won't work for the users/edit/123 because it'll navigate to not-existing /users/edit/ route.

Comment: +1 for an alternative but personally, I'm a bit of a byte chaser and would invest an extra dot in the parameter, *[".."]*, to eliminate reference to parent, *{ relativeTo: this.route }*.

Comment: awesome, thanks! I'm used to have empty Route full of children, so I needed to navigate `relativeTo: this.route.parent.parent` thanks again!

Answer (score 13):

without much ado:

```
this.router.navigate(['..'], {relativeTo: this.activeRoute, skipLocationChange: true});
```

parameter **'..'** makes navigation one level up, i.e. parent :)

Comment: You might want to mention the purpose/need of *skipLocationChange*.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, add a reference to what does the "this.activeRoute" is related to

Answer (score 9):

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

navigateOnParent() {
  this.router.navigate(['../some-path-on-parent']);
}
```

The router supports

- absolute paths `/xxx` - started on the router of the root component
- relative paths `xxx` - started on the router of the current component
- relative paths `../xxx` - started on the parent router of the current component

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @TobySpeight Fair enough. I assumed `../` is known well enough, but in the end it's still ambiguous. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've been working on this website for quite some time, so Angular as obviously been updated since. I've try this solution in my current version and it doesn't work. Let me update and I'll comment back after.

Comment: I don't get your code to work as expected. However, by adding explicitly *, { relativeTo: this.route }* as a second parameter in the call to *navigate*, it works. I'd chalk it up to a stupid typo if it hadn't been for the fact that your answers generally have an extreme degree of accuracy. Is it perhaps a change in behavior of the router since the answer was provided (3.6 years ago, which in Angular years is like a half'ish eternity)?

Comment: This is an old answer and the router changed a lot at this time. I think my answer is just outdated considering that there are several answers with more upvotes. I'm not doing that much web UI stuff anymore and don't have all details on the top of my head.

Answer (score 6):

To navigate to the parent **component** regardless of the number of parameters in the current route or the parent route: **Angular 6 update 1/21/19**

```
   let routerLink = this._aRoute.parent.snapshot.pathFromRoot
        .map((s) => s.url)
        .reduce((a, e) => {
            //Do NOT add last path!
            if (a.length + e.length !== this._aRoute.parent.snapshot.pathFromRoot.length) {
                return a.concat(e);
            }
            return a;
        })
        .map((s) => s.path);
    this._router.navigate(routerLink);
```

This has the added bonus of being an absolute route you can use with the singleton Router.

(Angular 4+ for sure, probably Angular 2 too.)

Comment: weirdly, this always returns an empty array, and achieves the same result as 
`this._router.navigate([])`, while `this._router.navigate([[]])` takes to the parent route, if and only if the parent route isn't root itself.

Comment: updated code to reflect Angular 6 changes and proper parent finding with parent and child containing children in routes.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't something specific to your use case? It would seem not appending the last path would turn ['orders', '123', 'items', 1] into just ['orders'], which doesn't seem right at all. In any case, we just went from Angular 5 to 7 and didn't touch this coded.

Comment: their are number of div on my page.. on click of every div i pass query parms and load a component. now using browser back button i want to go back how to do that?

Answer (score 6):

Another way could be like this

```
this._router.navigateByUrl(this._router.url.substr(0, this._router.url.lastIndexOf('/'))); // go to parent URL
```

and here is the constructor

```
constructor(
    private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router
  ) { }
```

Answer (score 2):

My routes have a pattern like this:

- user/edit/1 -> Edit
- user/create/0 -> Create
- user/ -> List

When i am on Edit page, for example, and i need go back to list page, i will return 2 levels up on the route.

Thinking about that, i created my method with a "level" parameter.

```
goBack(level: number = 1) {
    let commands = '../';
    this.router.navigate([commands.repeat(level)], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

So, to go from edit to list i call the method like that:

```
this.goBack(2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Everyone suggesting using relative paths really forgets about the most important part: the relative path always depends on the (possible) params you have in your route.

As an example, if you have a child route `edit/:id` and your id is an URI formatted like `/api/something/123` then in order to get to your parent using a relative route you need to use `[../../../..']`.
In other words, treat the URL like a directory structure on your computer. Don't think of the route in terms of the definition created in your routing table.

Answer (score 1):

None of this worked for me ... Here is my code with the back function :

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(private router: Router) {}
...
back() {
   this.router.navigate([this.router.url.substring(0, this.router.url.lastIndexOf('/'))]);
}
```

this.router.url.substring(0, this.router.url.lastIndexOf('/') --> get the last part of the current url after the "/" --> get the current route.

Comment: Please update your answer with some descriton why this works. Please see the [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the uiSref directive then you can do this

```
uiSref="^"
```

Answer (score -2):

My solution is:

```
const urlSplit = this._router.url.split('/');
this._router.navigate([urlSplit.splice(0, urlSplit.length - 1).join('/')], { relativeTo: this._route.parent });
```

And the `Router` injection:

```
private readonly _router: Router
```