# RouterLink to navigate back in child route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have few routes in my application. Parent route `admin` has few other child routes like `posts, about-me, categories`. I want to be able to access the child route and navigate back if the user wants to. I was trying to add a link

```
<a class="pointer" [routerLink]="['admin']">Back</a>
```

but, the Router was just adding this link to ActivatedRoute *(so the url looked like: http://localhost/admin/posts/admin)*.

So my question is what's the correct way to navigate back from the child route? Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196882/angular-2-routing-how-do-i-navigate-to-a-parent-route-from-a-child-route

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you wanted to redirect back to parent.

```
[routerLink]="['../../parent']"
```