# How to go back to a parent component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, routes, navigation, components

I want to go back to my parent componentn after a form is submitted in my AddUserComponent.

My url should change : `/video/1/user` to `/video/1`

I tried

```
this._router.navigate(['../../video'],{ relativeTo: this.route })
this._router.navigate(['../../video',{video_id:1}],{ relativeTo: this.route })
```

but it's not working.

My routes :

```
export const routes = [
  { path: '', component: VideosComponent },
  {
    path: 'video/:video_id',
    children :[
        { path: '', component: VideoComponent },
        { 
          path: 'user',
          children :[
              { path: '', component: AddUserComponent },
              { path: ':user_id', 
                children :[
                  { path: '', component: EditUserComponent}
                ]
              }
          ]
        },
    ]
}
];
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: have you checked [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38810729/2435473)?

Answer (score 0):

These should work

```
this._router.navigate(['../../video',1],{ relativeTo: this.route })
this._router.navigate(['../../video/' + 1],{ relativeTo: this.route })
this._router.navigate(['../../video/1'],{ relativeTo: this.route })
```

or absolute

```
this._router.navigate(['/video',1])
```

Comment: Thanks but url looks like video/1/user/video/1. I would like to get rid of 'user'.

Comment: Sounds like you are missing the `<base href="/">` in `<head>` (or a provider for `APP_BASE_HREF`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set/34535256#34535256

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`navigateByUrl`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#navigateByUrl-anchor)

```
this._router.navigateByUrl("/video/1");
```