# Navigation Error in Angular path

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I, have the below route

```
{
        path: '', component: FrontEndMainComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: FrontEndHomeComponent },
            { path: 'login', component: CustomerAuthComponent }
        ]
    },
```

When I, tried to navigate to login or home from login it gives me an error as shown below.

[image: erro description]

[image: error details]

Here is the html code for navigation

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="example-toolbar">
            <a  [routerLink]="['home']"><img src="../../assets/logo.png"/></a>
            <div>
                  <a mat-raised-button color="primary" [routerLink]="['login']">Login</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <a mat-raised-button color="primary" [routerLink]="['signup']">Sign up</a>

            </div>

      </mat-toolbar>
```

some of the link I checked 
https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-child-routes-and-relative-navigation-example

[How do I navigate to a parent route from a child route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196882/how-do-i-navigate-to-a-parent-route-from-a-child-route)

Comment: Does changing your `routerLink` to this `[routerLink]="['/home']"` (add the slash in front), help?

Answer (score -1):

Try with the following, you should add a **`/`**

```
<a  [routerLink]="['/home']"><img src="../../assets/logo.png"/></a>
```

Comment: It should be `img src="assets/logo.png"`  CLI knows about the asset folder

Comment: Does not matter though

Comment: Agree with vikas. Furthermore, why dont you add some small explanation as to what is the difference in this approach and why should it work?