# Angular 6 how can I go back to parent then come to child in router.navigate()

Tags: angular7, angular-router

Hi I'm having parent component 'Order' and two child component for it 'History' and 'Orders'. Current url is `order/history/id` I want to go back to 'Orders' component `like order/orders/id` so I'm using Router in my app.

```
this.router.navigate(['../../orders', orderId]);
```

in history component as suggested in [How do I navigate to a parent route from a child route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196882/how-do-i-navigate-to-a-parent-route-from-a-child-route)  but it showing `cannot match any routes url segment  orders/7y6786` What is the best approach to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Use `navigateByUrl` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using the navigate inside a component, you may use the `ActivatedRoute` service.

So in you History Component, try to do this:

```
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router
) {}

navigateToOrders() {
  this.router.navigate(['orders', orderId], { relativeTo: this.route.parent })
}
```