# Angular: How to navigate to child route from parent component by using navigate method

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular8

Here is my html rouerLink:

`<a [routerLink]="['create']">Create</a>` - works fine.

on button click I am calling the same as: But not works..

```
navigateTo(page) {
        this.router.navigate(['create']); //not works
    }
```

Any one help me, what is really I am missing here?

**UPDATE**

I am navigating from parent to child

here is the routes:

```
{
                path: 'contentPlaceholder',
                data: { showNavi: true },
                component: ShellContentPlaceholderComponent,

                children : [
                    {
                        path: 'view',
                        data: { showNavi: false },
                        component: ShellContentViewPlaceholderComponent,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'create',
                        data: { showNavi: false },
                        component: ShellContentCreatePlaceholderComponent,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'edit',
                        data: { showNavi: false },
                        component: ShellContentEditPlaceholderComponent,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'update',
                        data: { showNavi: false },
                        component: ShellContentUpdatePlaceholderComponent,
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Comment: @PrashantPimpale - I am at `contentPlaceholder`

Comment: [Must read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196882/how-do-i-navigate-to-a-parent-route-from-a-child-route)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try by setting [`relativeTo`](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras) value to current Route:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

and then:

```
this.router.navigate(['./create'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```