# Unable to navigate to the new page on icon click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, angular-routing

I am trying to navigate to the new page on click of the icon and the component is like below

```
getTabDetails() {
  switch (this.tabContent) {
    case 'Shipment content':
      {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/ProjectShipment/000634');
      }
  }
}
```

And my Routing component is like below

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
  path: 'dB',
  data: { title: 'Dashboard' },
  children: [
      {
          path: 'ProjectShipment/:reportProject',
          component: ProjectShipmentComponent,
          data: { title: 'Project Shipment' },
      }
```

I get the below error when the icon is clicked

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'ProjectShipment/000634'
>   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'ProjectShipment/000634'

but when I try to access the page directly through URL it works

http://localhost:4200/dB/ProjectShipment/000634

Am I missing something here?

Comment: what is that `dB`? is it path?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Yes dB is the path. I have updated the question

Comment: So you are currently at `http://localhost:4200/dB` path?

Comment: Check accepted answer on:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57473394/angular-how-to-navigate-to-child-route-from-parent-component-by-using-navigate/57473645#57473645

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(['ProjectShipment',000634], relativeTo:this.route);
```

where

```
private route: ActivatedRoute
```

in case you are at /dB path

Answer (score 0):

```js
self.router.navigate(['./ProjectShipment/000634']);
```